# How to calibrate the MLX90616 IR temperature sensor?

Tags: i2c, infrared, calibration

I have purchased some Melexis mlx90616 IR temperature sensors. The data sheet states that a calibration “by the customer” is required. By contacting my purchaser I got the answer: "The supplier has gotten back to us saying that they have limited resources available for technical support regarding the MLX90616".

It turns out that Melexis is not interested to offer support regarding the calibration procedure for the mlx90616 for those not buying high number of units.

Does anyone know how to calibrate the mlx90616, or at least the sequence of how to update the “read only” calibration coefficient registers? By having the information of how to, it would be an easy task to write the needed software.

Background info:

The returned object temperature readings (I2C/SMBus) are very slow changing and always close to the on-chip ambient temperature. Reading the raw IR channels shows rapid change when pointing to objects with different temperatures.

Reading the writable eeprom calibration coefficient register 0x2F returns 0x0020. The other eeprom read-only calibration registers (e.g. 0x26 to 0x2D) returns 0x00, which indicates that a calibration is needed. The equvialent regsisters on the comparable unit mlx90614, which is factory calibrated, is different from zero.

However, the procedure of how to calibrate the mlx90616 seems hard to find. There is no info in the datasheet regarding how to update the calibration registers, nor how to determine the values.

Comment: In my datasheet it is stated: "Please consult Melexis for more information on the calibration procedure of the MLX90616.", which of course is done.  But as stated  "At the time of writing, Melexis has not answered queries regarding the calibration procedure. " 

I would have appreciated answers to my question. The other posts in this forum regarding mlx90616 does not answer my question.

Comment: Link to datasheet, please, in your original question and not in the comments.

Comment: Access to the datasheet is only for registered users of Melexis. Hence no link.

Comment: No it's not. It's [here](http://www.melexis.com/Asset/IR-sensor-thermometer-MLX90616-Datasheet-DownloadLink-6089.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. When I downloaded it, I had to register as a user.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, you need to build the prototype (or complete) system around the MLX90616 that includes the appropriate (likely microcontroller) interface and processing, then you need to take measurements against objects of known temperature and emissivity. With that data, you can develop coefficients/constants to use in the function that translates the MLX90616 digital output value into a temperature value.

Comment: Yes, that is probably the only option, as long as the detailed info regarding how to calibrate the mlx90616 is not known. I already have the prototype up and running using the mlx90614/616 and RPi2.
Given that the raw data from the IR channels is Vir, object temperature is To, ambient temp.  is Ta, emmisivity is emm and the unknown calibration coeff is alpha, the equation to take into account is:

Vir = alpha*emm*(To^4 - Ta^4).

Ta is factory calibrated and available in the mlx90616.
Assuming emm of the object is known and that To is known/measured, it is an easy task to determine alpha

Comment: My only concern is that the raw data (Vir) is not listed as accessable in the datasheet for the mlx90616 and mlx90614. However, the address of the raw data registers are given and reading them returns values that changes with object temperature, so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

My solution seems to be:

Given that the raw data from the IR channels is Vir, object temperature is To, ambient temp. is Ta, emmisivity is emm and the unknown calibration coeff is alpha, the equation to take into account is:

Vir = alpha * emm * (To^4 - Ta^4)                        (eq. 1)

Used one of my mlx90614 to measure the object temperature (To) in the attempt to estimate alpha in equation (1). Let alpha be a function of Ta and Vir-VirComp as well as compensating for the gain in the mlx90616 (VirComp is the IR compensating register value read from the mlx90616). Both the mlx90614 and mlx90616 was measuring the same object and the readings of the registers in the mlx'es was done as fast as possible using I2C/SMBus at 100kHz connected to a RPi2, and with sample time of 200ms. Used least square fit to determine the coeffisients in alpha (b=A\x in matlab syntax for those familiar with matlab).

Tested the concept on a small range of temperatures only, but it seems like this could be a way to use the mlx90616 for those who do not get support from Melexis. At least it is not a show stopper any more...
[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. Presumably they'll eventually release an EVB for this part, with software.